# How do I use concat and case switch together in PostgresSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, switch-statement

I am trying to use concat as function and inside the same function use case switch statements in PostgresSQL. The end goal is populating a table with a bunch of statements that change according to the case.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

I tried to use '+' and ',' but I always get the same Syntax error

```
(SELECT concat(cast(idpersonale as varchar(5)),' = ' 
        ,case when dstitolo is not null then dstitolo else '' end + ' ' 
        ,case when dsnome is not null then dsnome else '' end + ' '  
        ,case when dscognome is not null then dscognome else '' end 
dscognome)
    FROM global.glb_personale
    WHERE cch.glb_personale.idpersonale =inter.interventoeseguitoda) as InterventoEseguitoDa
FROM cch.pats_cch_interventi inter
WHERE (idtiporecord is null or not idtiporecord in('uti','int')) and
    NOT idintervento IN (SELECT idint
                           FROM cch.glo_error_data_2
                           WHERE (iddb = 'cch') AND (cnerror = 1))    
order by idintervento;
```

Comment: What error did you get when using `,` instead of `+`?

Comment: Hello, I get a syntax error by "dscognome" in the last case statement. In particular the error is:

Comment: Errore SQL [42601]: ERRORE: errore di sintassi a o presso "dscognome"

Comment: You are missing comma after your last CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END and before column `dscognome` and I don't mean that column being used in last case, but after that case (last element of concat function). So go back to `,` instead of `+` and add that missing comma.

Comment: This type of error usually means that your question should be closed, since those are unlikely to help anyone else (they are offtopic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenation works with `||` operator or `concat(text1, text2, text3, ...)` function. Every text literal can be also an expression which gives a type `text`, like a `CASE` clause:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=127ca65b16c7f1d0c784dd9595cb3b89)

```
SELECT 
    'you' || 'can' || 'concat' || 'like' || 'that' AS concat1,
    concat('or', 'like', 'that') AS concat2,
    concat('Mix' || 'both', 'up') AS concat3,
    concat(
         'And',
         CASE WHEN false THEN 'now' ELSE 'doint' END || 'this', 
         CASE 
             WHEN true THEN 'with' || 'some'
             WHEN false THEN 'CASE'
             ELSE 'clauses' 
         END
    ) AS concat4
```

That means in your case: Change `concat(text1 + text2 + text3)` to `concat(text1, text2, text3)` (because the texts are function arguments) or to `text1 || text2 || text3`

Answer (score 1):

While the concatenation operator (||) and the function (concat) combine strings there is a big difference between them: how they handle nulls.

- If any operand is null then the concatenation operator result is NULL.
- If any operand is null then the concatenation function moves to the next operand, leaving previous and subsequent results as they would had the null operand not been present. Example:

  ```
  with dscognome (idpersonale,dstitolo ,dsnome ,dscognome) as
         ( values (1,'a','b','c')
                , (2,'d','e',null)
                , (3,'f',null,'g')
                , (4,null, 'h', 'i')
                , (5,null, null, null)
         )
      select idpersonale 
           , dstitolo || dsnome || dscognome    "using || opreator"
           , concat(dstitolo,dsnome,dscognome)  "using concat function"
  ```

  from dscognome;

Since the entire purpose of the case structure is to handle nulls, using the concatenation function entirely negates it's requirement and the query can be written:

```
with dscognome (idpersonale,dstitolo ,dsnome ,dscognome) as
   ( values (1,'a','b','c')
          , (2,'d','e',null)
          , (3,'f',null,'g')
          , (4,null, 'h', 'i')
          , (5,null, null, null)
   )
SELECT concat(cast(idpersonale as varchar),' = ' 
        , dstitolo , ' ' 
        , dsnome, ' ' 
        , dscognome  )
from dscognome;
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are using `concat()`, replace `+` to `,` instead.

```
(SELECT concat(cast(idpersonale as varchar(5)),' = ' 
        ,case when dstitolo is not null then dstitolo else '' end, ' ' 
        ,case when dsnome is not null then dsnome else '' end, ' '  
        ,case when dscognome is not null then dscognome else '' end 
dscognome)
    FROM global.glb_personale
    WHERE cch.glb_personale.idpersonale =inter.interventoeseguitoda) as InterventoEseguitoDa
FROM cch.pats_cch_interventi inter
WHERE (idtiporecord is null or not idtiporecord in('uti','int')) and
    NOT idintervento IN (SELECT idint
                           FROM cch.glo_error_data_2
                           WHERE (iddb = 'cch') AND (cnerror = 1))
```